# Access denied when trying to authenticate through oauth

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I can get access by getting auth token from browser and using "Fetch..." later.
But I want to do it without user intervention.
I decided to use Service account.
But when i'm trying to get access,
I always receive "access denied".
I'm using

```
var oAuth2Provider =
                (user.OAuthProvider as AdsOAuthProviderForServiceAccounts);
        oAuth2Provider.GenerateAccessTokenForServiceAccount();
```

The properties of oAuth2Provider are:

> JwtCertificatePassword    "notasecret"
>         JwtCertificatePath  "D://xxxxx-privatekey.p12"
>         PrnEmail    "jrusearchbroadtwomycc@gmail.com" //it's my mcc account with
>   approved dev token
>         ServiceAccountEmail "22222222222-ckvf630rcccn3j7jjuf4fmujnbiotett@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

Here are stack trace of error.

```
    at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderForServiceAccounts.GenerateAccessTokenForServiceAccount()
   at AdwordsStat.GetReports.DoAuth2Authorization(AdsUser user) in D:\Adwords_API\Jooble_Adwords\GetReports.cs:line 48
   at AdwordsStat.Form1.Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Adwords_API\Jooble_Adwords\Form1.cs:line 87
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CallShownEvent()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at AdwordsStat.Program.Main() in D:\Adwords_API\Jooble_Adwords\Program.cs:line 16
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Then I've read about neediness of google apps account.
I've registered,added to it's account cliend id from my service account that looks like

> 2222222222222-ckvf630rcccn3j7jjuf4fmujnbiotett.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   scope : https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/

But I get access denied again.

Then i've tried to use another lib which looks like 
`

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAccessToken(string clientIdEMail, string keyFilePath, string scope)
        {
            // certificate
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret");

        // header
        var header = new { typ = "JWT", alg = "RS256" };

        // claimset
        var times = GetExpiryAndIssueDate();
        var claimset = new
        {
            iss = clientIdEMail,
            scope = scope,
            aud = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            iat = times[0],
            exp = times[1],
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // encoded header
        var headerSerialized = ser.Serialize(header);
        var headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerSerialized);
        var headerEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(headerBytes);

        // encoded claimset
        var claimsetSerialized = ser.Serialize(claimset);
        var claimsetBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(claimsetSerialized);
        var claimsetEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(claimsetBytes);

        // input
        var input = headerEncoded + "." + claimsetEncoded;
        var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

        // signiture
        var rsa = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        var cspParam = new CspParameters
        {
            KeyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
            KeyNumber = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber == KeyNumber.Exchange ? 1 : 2
        };
        var aescsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam) { PersistKeyInCsp = false };
        var signatureBytes = aescsp.SignData(inputBytes, "SHA256");
        var signatureEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);

        // jwt
        var jwt = headerEncoded + "." + claimsetEncoded + "." + signatureEncoded;

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        var content = new NameValueCollection();

        content["assertion"] = jwt;
        content["grant_type"] = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", content));

        var result = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);

        return result;
    }

    private static int[] GetExpiryAndIssueDate()
    {
        var utc0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var issueTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var iat = (int)issueTime.Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;
        var exp = (int)issueTime.AddMinutes(55).Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;

        return new[] { iat, exp };
    }`
```

And after that-i've receiving access token and expiry time.

```
var result = GetAccessToken(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, SCOPE_ANALYTICS_READONLY);
            string access_token;
            result.TryGetValue("access_token", out access_token);
```

then I'm trying to

```
oAuth2Provider.AccessToken = access_token;
```

But again receiving access denied

I've been trying to solve this problem for a week.

Comment: Is someone can help me with my problem???

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: i solved it.
i'm using google apps account to retrieve access to api now.
And i've registered this account as my client center.

Comment: Me too, but had a different problem: set the scope as `https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords` without the trailing slash, like it says [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/service-accounts#steps). It turns out that the trailing slash is a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not 100% obvious what you’re really trying to accomplish, but if you need to have offline access on behalf of a user, what you probably want is a “refresh token”, so you can get a new access token when your initial one expires. The info is at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: I'm trying to get access without user intervention.  
It would start on our server every night.
So i wouldn't have access and chance to getting access token manually